# Measuring time between client starts request in browser until server gets it

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

Is there a way to measure this?

Certainly, for get requests, no available headers are being sent consistently from clients.

One idea I got is to get that from query string, but is that possible? Something like (pseudo-code follows)

```
http://server/default.aspx?t=(new Date().getTime())
```

Another one that would work is to have users hit a very small page that appends a query string as above, but wanted to avoid a redirection if possible.

(Overall goal is to gather per-request such statistics. The server processing time and server to client are more doable, under some assumptions.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I've done this through an AJAX request after the initial page load where you have control over the request from the very beginning.  Pass the UNIX time in the query string and then when it reaches the server take the difference.  I'm not familiar with iis7 so you'd have to make sure that timezone's are accounted for.  This number could be very erratic since it's basically just calculating latency and DNS lookups which is different for every client.

Answer (score 0):

Does the request start from an initial page that you have control over it ? in that case you can send the server time with the initial response, and then increment that time second-by-second with a javascript code while the user is on the page. this way you can have a server-synchronized time on the page and when a request goes to be sent from that page you can send that synced time with that request, then all you need is calculate difference on the server.